Publishing a toolbox in Web AppBuilder
I would like to add a geoprocessing tool widget in Web AppBuilder. I designed this tool in ArcGIS Pro using a Python script. However, I'm having trouble publishing my toolbox, which works fine in ArcGIS Pro, to ArcGIS Server in order to get the URL needed to integrate it into Web AppBuilder.
How can I solve this problem? Can you give me some recommendations?
